# Convert Char to Hex from Serial Port

Tags: java, serial-port, type-conversion

I basically implemented a method in which I will read the input incoming from a serial port (RS232).

```
void read() throws IllegalStateException, IllegalArgumentException, ATCommandFailedException{
String hexch="";
String hex="";
String chave="";




//  System.out.println(" RS232 Standby...");
try {
  int char = -1;
  while(char != 13) {
    char = inStream.read();

    if (ch >= 0) {
      chave += (char) char; // Input char type in the String
      hex = Integer.toHexString(ch);
      hexch += hex;     // Input hex type in the String 
    }   
  }            
}
```

This is working perfectly. Although, to assure that the process is efficient in long term usage, I want to make the conversion outside the reading moment. The problem is that since my project is made in JavaME I'm not able to use any String.format method's,etc.
Can someone point me any solution?
Thanks :)

Comment: If you worry about performance I would first check if that string concatenation using "+" is really the best way to do. Cant you use a Stringbuilder there? And please understand: questions about *working* code might better go to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The other thing: i would also look into my naming. hex, chave, hexch ... are all pretty nothing-saying names. Same for the name of that method.

Comment: Hello GhostCat. Unfortunatly I can't. The java modem I'm using only allows me to work under 1.3IDE which is limiting me a lot.

Comment: I´m afraid to say that in java 1.3 concatenation using "+" was still a pain in the ...